Issue when trying to enable LDAPS - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching [DNS] found
I am trying to enable LDAPS on Confluence app running on Linux. I have a DNS alias and behind it are some AD domain controllers. Connection to each one of them from the Linux host is tested as working on port 636.
I have imported into the cacerts truststore used by the app the certificate which has the DNS alias in its SAN field :
#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: dns.alias.com
]

Yet when I try to test LDAPS connection from the app (after restarting it) I still get the below :
Connection test failed. Response from the server:
dns.alias.com:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: dns.alias.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching dns.alias.com found.]

The app is using java 11. Could anyone suggest what could be the issue here ?


Why are you importing host certificates into the "cacerts" truststore? 2) Can you test the connection specifically using a TLS client (e.g. gnutls-cli or openssl s_client) so that you could see whether the server is offering the correct certificate?

